# CSS Dropdown Menu - List items not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

Check out the [JSFiddel Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UfpCm/)

I have a CSS Based dropdown menu that drops down on hover but all lists displayed on hover are in the same location, not under the menu item they are associated with. I believe the problem lies with this part of the code...

```
#menu ul li {
}
```

but even when I edit this and take away the float I can't seem to figure it out.  Maybe someone can point out the mistake I've made.  Thanks in advance for the help.

CSS

```
#menu ul {
font-family: Arial, Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
display: inline;
}
#menu ul li {
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
#menu li ul {
display: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
background: #1e7c9a;
margin-left: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
#menu li:hover li {
float: none;
font-size: 11px;
}
#menu li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
#menu li:hover li a:hover {
background: #1e7c9a;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Find Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Logo Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Our Menu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">This is a project</a></li>
<li><a href="#">So is this</a></li>
<li><a href="#">and this</a></li>
<li><a href="#">don't forget this too</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Our Story</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Quote</a></li>
<li><a href="#">General Enquiry</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to put this into jsfiddle?

Comment: For LI, either use inline-block or float:left.

Comment: Baldrs the JSfiddle link is at the top of the post. @Diodeus thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UfpCm/1/

Use `inline-block` on `#menu li`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it's always the small things that get you.